# Why TransactionalEventListener is not working in transaction?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, events, spring-transactions

I have implemented event publisher, but it doesnt work as I expect.
I try to configure events publishing only for successful transaction commit asynchronously.

Example of usage:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public FooDto getFooByUuid(final String uuid) {
        ...findFooByUuid(uuid)...
        auditClient.publishEvent(new Event(foo)); // published only if transaction didn't rolled back.
        ... some code
        return fooDto;
    }
```

I have the following config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ApplicationConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {


    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Bean(name = "publishPoolTaskExecutor")
    @Primary
    public Executor publishPoolTaskExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("publisher-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

and I have AuditClient

```
...
    @Async(value = "publishPoolTaskExecutor")
    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
    public void publishEvent(EventDto<?> event) {
    try {
                String eventString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(event);
                String response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                    url,
                    eventString,
                    String.class
                ).getBody();
                log.info(response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ...
            }
     }
```

When exception is thrown in getFooByUuid method - event still publishes.
How should I configure publishEvent method, that will be executed ONLY in case transaction successfully committed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a problem that listener couldn't obtain information about transaction? Try to use

```
@TransactionalEventListener(fallbackExecution = true)
```

If it helps - that means that in some reason transaction info is lost after publishing event